# Cleaning and grouping values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', encoding='ISO-8859-1') 

column_names = list(df.columns)
col_mapping = {'Sex ':'Sex', 'Fatal (Y/N)': 'Fatal', 'Species ' : 'Species'}
df = df.rename(columns=col_mapping, copy=False)
```

I've transformed the data as that the values from df['Age'] column that contains letter or other symbols take the value NaN

```
df['Age'] = np.where(pd.to_numeric(df['Age'], 'coerce').notnull(), df['Age'], NaN)
```

I've tried to use `df.dropna(df.Age)` to clean the `NaN` values but it gives me: TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

I want to know how to set this problem and how to group and count the resulting values bu range (i.e 18 - 25 years : 215, 25 - 50 : 300) for future ploting

Comment: In order to help with the grouping, you need to show some sample data and  give a better description of what you want to see.  see this post for guidance http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to use the parameter `subset`

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['Age'])
```

Comment: It doesn't work, any changes, when I print out the df['Age'] there are still NaN values

Comment: you must assign it

Comment: how can I group the values by range?

Comment: There is an easy answer but in order to show you, I need to see an example of you data.  Also, you need to provide a better description of what you want the output to look like.

Comment: df['Age'] is a list of strings with ages of from 5 to 100. I want to clasify that people by age, the output should be like: from 5 to 10 years : 10, from 10 to 20 years : 25. I want to count the number of people that went in these ranges and plot them.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer four grouping question:

```
df['Age']=df[['Age']].astype(int)
Grouped_Age = pd.cut(df.Age,[5, 10, 20, 50, 100], right=True)
Age_counts = Grouped_Age.value_counts()
```